# Understanding how JS Module Pattern works

Tags: javascript, jquery, design-patterns, namespaces, module-pattern

I'm trying to understand js module patterns in use with jQuery. I've edited this a couple of times and will try to end up with a good practice for my skill level (a couple of months fresh on jquery).

There's no direct question in this post. I'm more aiming for feedback and inputs on how to properly use the module pattern (together with jquery) in a large scale website.

**Update**: I've added a bunch of examples in order to get an overview of all ways of writing things, and try to cover any pitfalls..

```
/* 
Not all browsers works with console.log, so we want to make sure that
console.log is defined. This defines the consol.log and send the messages
into an alert.
*/
if(!window.console) console = {
  log: function(s) { 
    alert(s); // alert since we dont have the firebug console
  }
};

// Check if namespace is defined
if (typeof (CompanyName) === 'undefined') {
    CompanyName = {};
}

// Or if AppName under CompanyName...

if (typeof (CompanyName.AppName) === 'undefined') {
    CompanyName.AppName = {};
}

// Our namespace
CompanyName.AppName = (function ($) {

    // CHAINING
    var _first = function () {
        // Important to always start with "var"
    },

    _second = function () {
        // Chained (  ...},  ) so it doesnt need "var"
    },

    _third = "Just a var", // Variables just ends with ,

    _four = "Another var"; // Closing the chain with ;

    var _anotherFirst = function () {
        // Previous chain of var's was ended with ; so this var needed "var" in order to start.
    };

    g_globalVar = "I'm free!"; // When starting a var without "var", it becomes global.

    g_globalMethod = function () { 
        alert("I'm free too!"); // Global method.
    };

    g_chainedGlobalVarOne = "We are free!",
    g_chainedGlobalVarTwo = "We are free!";

    // Private Variables
    var _privateVar = "privateVar: accessed from within AppLaunch.Admin namespace";

    // Private Methods
    var _privateMethod = function () {
       log("privateMethod: accessed only from within AppLaunch.Admin");
    }; // Last variable in a chain must always end with ; before the return {}

    function log() {
        if (window.console && window.console.log)
            window.console.log('[AppName] ' + Array.prototype.join.call(arguments, ' '));
    };

    return {
        init: function () {

            // Calling private
            _privateMethod();

            // Calling Public
            this.myPublicMethod();

            // Also Calling Public
            CompanyName.AppName.myPublicMethod();

            // Calling Other namespace's Public Method (when exists)
            CompanyName.OtherNamespace.externalPublicMethod(); 
        },

        // Public
        myPublicMethod: function() {
            log("myPublicMethod");
        },
        // In a View (MVC), I could have a page called myPage where I want to init
        // some particular functions. myPage can be called just like init. 
        myPage: function() { 
            _second();
            _third();
        }

    }
})(jQuery); 

// Initialize
jQuery().ready(function() {
    CompanyName.AppName.init()
    CompanyName.AppName.myPublicMethod();
});
```

#### Trying to understand what's happening (Feel free to provide corrections or better explanations):

```
Company.AppName = (function ($) { ...
```

Here the namespace Company.AppName is created. I set ($) inside so I can use the $ without it conflicting with any other libraries that might use $.

```
})(jQuery);
```

As far as I know, the methods and variables are returned to the namespace here ...})(); and by adding jQuery inside () it'll tell it that the $ means jQuery.

#### Initializing

I'm not sure what's best practice here, but I'll add what I know so far.

Initializing within js file:

```
jQuery(function() { 
    AppLaunch.Admin.init();
});
```

Initializing from a file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Shorthand for jQuery(document).ready(function() { ... }

jQuery(function($) { 
    AppLaunch.Admin.init($('#someSelector'));     
});
</script>
```

Comment: I found that this example helped a great deal. I have made a few edits so that you can simply copy and paste the JavaScript and it works without any tweaks (namespace for example).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are many places that will give you an in depth explanation of the module pattern; jQuery's usage of it is pretty standard.

This is just one of the many [module pattern explanations out there](http://www.klauskomenda.com/code/javascript-programming-patterns/#module).

Comment: Agree, there's no such thing as 'the jQuery module pattern'. If you have a specific question about how it's usually used within jquery, that would be more useful for SO

Comment: Hehe, yea that was me defining it a bit wrong. I meant module pattern in general, but in use with jQuery. Great link btw! I think I can understand how things work a bit better from this :)