# Javascript error ; while trying locally

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

the below code gives "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getContext' of undefined". The code is my experiment to port a canvas app using module pattern as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4311949/understanding-how-js-module-pattern-works).

Please find the same code in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kmv8Y/), which works fine.

thanks.

//====test.html ========

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Location</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<canvas id="cvs" height="600" width="800"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

//==test.js ========

```
if (typeof (NS) === 'undefined') {
    NS = {};
}

NS.AppName = (function ($) {
// Private members
    /*var _first = function () {
    },
    _second = function () {
    },*/
    var _cvs = $("#cvs");
    var _ctx = _cvs.get(0).getContext("2d");    

    var _privateVar = "privateVar: accessed from within AppLaunch.Admin namespace";
    // Private Methods
    var _privateMethod = function () {
       log("privateMethod: accessed only from within AppLaunch.Admin");
    }; // Last variable in a chain must always end with ; before the return {}

    function log() {
        if (window.console && window.console.log)
            window.console.log('[AppName] ' + Array.prototype.join.call(arguments, ' '));
    };

    return {
        init: function () {
        },

        // Public
        myPublicMethod: function() {
            //alert("myPublicMethod" + _cvs.height());
            _ctx.fillRect(25,25,100,100);
    _ctx.clearRect(45,45,60,60);
    _ctx.strokeRect(50,50,50,50);
        }
    }
})(jQuery); 

// Initialize
jQuery().ready(function() {
    NS.AppName.init()
    NS.AppName.myPublicMethod();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you get an error is that the [self executing anonymous function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186024/how-do-you-explain-this-structure-in-javascript) used to initialize `NS.AppName` is invoked in place (right where it is defined), and not when the DOM is ready.

```
NS.AppName = (function ($) {
  //1: some code
  return function(){...}//2
}(jQuery));//3

$(function(){
  NS.AppName();//4
});
```

**line 3** is the *self executing* part. It calls the anonymous function declared above.

During the call of **line 3** the body of the anonymous function will be executed (**including line 1**, but not anything inside the function at **line 2**). If the document is not loaded when this happens (ex: if the script is in the head), than it will fail because there is no `$("#cvs")` in the DOM yet.

**Line 4** will call the function defined at **line 2** *when the DOM is fully loaded* (`$(f)` is equivalent to `$(document).ready(f)`).

Here is some more info about self executing anonymous functions, or using a better name "[Immediately-Invoked Function Expression](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/)"

You can fix the script in three ways:

- Remove any references to the DOM from the anonymous function, and move them in the returned one (I'd do this, it's just one element...)
- Wrap the entire script in `jQuery(function($){...(you can safely use $ here, so no need for the anonymous functions)...});` - execute it all on DOM ready
- Move it at the bottom of the page (not ideal, but it would work)

Answer (score 1):

Your `ready` handler syntax is incorrect - try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    NS.AppName.init();
    NS.AppName.myPublicMethod();
});
```

Or

```
jQuery(function() {
    NS.AppName.init();
    NS.AppName.myPublicMethod();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't get an error.  But perhaps something is lost in translation from you c/ping it here. Perhaps (and this is just a guess), put a ; on the end of that `NS.AppName.init()` maybe you have some funky whitespace/returns going on there...

Answer (score 0):

Moving the JS to body solved the problem:

```
    <html>
<head>
    <title>Location</title>
</head>

<body>
<canvas id="cvs" height="600" width="800"></canvas>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

or

```
    <html>
<head>
    <title>Location</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<canvas id="cvs" height="600" width="800"></canvas>     
    <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```